# Отсутствие перевода вкладки браузера при фильтрации вопросов

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, фильтрация-вопросов

При фильтрации вопросов в пользовательском фильтре вкладка браузера отображает такой текст:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

попадаем мы сюда так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[ссылка для ознакомления](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=Newest&filters=NoAnswers&edited=true)

Comment: У меня нормально. Можно прямую ссылку?

Comment: @Qwertiy, отредактировал вопрос, посмотрите у вас все видно?

Comment: Да, у меня нормально. И в приватном окне без входа на сайт - тоже.

Comment: а от чего это может зависеть кроме браузера? может стоит добавить контекста связанного с машиной где я сижу?

Comment: Сомнительно, скорее с выбранными параметрами. По крайней мере, если в консоли ошибок нет. Попробуй в приватном окне без логина то же самое. Кстати, скрипты же включены?

Comment: @Qwertiy удалось повторить при пустом списке в "Указанные ниже метки:" и наличии хотя бы одной галочки "Без ответов" или "Объявлен конкурс".

Comment: да именно так нужно было) я ведь специально с галочками скрин прикрепил) если просто перейти на ту ссылку что я скинул без галочек то там будет на русском языке

Comment: @Andrew, вроде соответсует скриншоту: https://i.stack.imgur.com/98mJ7.png

Comment: @Qwertiy, а вы нажали на кнопку принятия фильтра? просто если галку включить и не отфильтровать то будет такая ситуация как у вас на скриншоте

Comment: @Andrew, получилось. Что мешало сразу дать полную ссылку в вопросе? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=Newest&filters=NoAnswers&edited=true

Comment: @Qwertiy, извините что так получилось, скопировал ту что до фильтрации :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хотя у меня тоже не удалось воспроизвести проблему, вероятно, не выполняются какие-то важные предусловия. Однако, пары переводов, действительно, не было. Добавил их:

- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16062
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16044

Будет на сайте в новых сборках. Текущая rev 2021.4.15.39090

P.S. Всё же удалось повторить при пустом списке в "Указанные ниже метки:" и наличии хотя бы одной галочки "Без ответов" или "Объявлен конкурс". Собственно как на картинке у ТС.

Comment: спасибо большое :)